How to prevent the SPLIT function from converting text to non-text in Google Sheets
I have a comma-delimited list of words in a single spreadsheet cell, such as this:
 hello, True, Franklin, true, goodbye 
The SPLIT() function extracts each word into its own cell.
Except that it turns the word "true" into the Boolean value TRUE:
 hello   TRUE   Franklin   TRUE   goodbye 
I want to split each word into its own cell, but to create only text values, and to maintain the original case of each word:
 hello   True   Franklin   true   goodbye 
Any ideas? Here is a demonstration spreadsheet showing the result of SPLIT, as compared to the expected/desired result.

This should really be a feature request: Don't change type  when splitting...

Legacy behavior, unlikely to change. The problem is even worse with =split("1-3,4-7,8-10", ",") that gives three dates because of automatic coercion.

@doubleunary Maybe the default behaviour doesn't need to change, but it is still possible to add a new argument to SPLIT for this functionality: the 5th argument - no_type_change

You can use:
=SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE("'"&C1,", ",", '"),", ") 

More generic:
=LET(del,", ",SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE("'"&C1,del,del&"'"),del)) 


Thank you! I made the lower version into a named function with del as an argument instead of a LET and it works great!

Use regexextract(), like this:
=let( 
  data, C1, 
  delimiter, ", ", 
  numDelimiters, (len(data) - len(substitute(data, delimiter, ""))) / len(delimiter), 
  regexextract(data, rept("(.*)" & delimiter, numDelimiters) & "(.*)") 
)

See regexextract().


You may try:
=sort(substitute(split(regexreplace(C1,"^|, ","$0⁤"),", ",),"⁤",))



This is an interesting approach (even if slightly overkill), but useless/counterproductive if not explained.
